# Wait until unarchiveObjectWithData method is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm using [archivedDataWithRootObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) / [unarchiveObjectWithData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html): methods to serialize / deserialize a list of strings relative to images to load from the device in my app.

So when `unarchiveObjectWithData` method is executed:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"basket"]]
```

It will call `initWithCoder` method from Picture class for each picture to deserialize. This method retrieves the asset from the specified URL :

```
[[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] assetForURL: [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"imageUrl"];] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    if (asset)
    {
        self.picture = asset;            
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

I put a breakpoint on `self.picture = asset;` and saw that the picture is successfully retrieved.

Then, just after the call of `unarchiveObjectWithData` method, I want display the retrieved images on `UIImageViews`. But I saw that the UIImageViews were displayed on screen before the pictures were successfully retrieved. So the UIImageViews are always empties.

I would wait for `unarchiveObjectWithData` method be done before displaying the images.

I tried to do something like :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [BasketManager setSharedInstance:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"basket"]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[(Picture *)BasketItemByID([(NSMutableDictionary *)CurrentBasket allKeys][0]) picture]];
        [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure that assetForURL returns an asset ? after closing and opening the app agian ?

Comment: Yes, sure. When I test, I close and reopen the app.

Comment: Create a method to add the images as subviews, and call this method inside
`assetForURL:resultBlock:` block (which is after the images have been retrieved).

Comment: that is weird because according to Apple doc: > The lifetimes of objects you get back from a library instance are tied to the lifetime of the library instance.

Comment: @gWiz Mmmh, the method to add the UIImageView as a subview should be in the controller that unarchive the datas and I should call it from the `Picture` class model in `initWithCoder:` method. But Picture model doesn't have any pointer of the desired controller.

Comment: @Bobj-C But this is weird because when I put a breakpoint on `self.picture = asset;` after restarted my app, the desired image is shown.

Comment: I see 2 solutions: 1) Have a timer wait for all pictures to finish loading (each picture should have a BOOL loaded), 2) Create a protocol and pass your controller as the delegate of the Picture object, so in your loaded block call `[self.delegate reloadThisPicture];`

Comment: Problem solved. Finally I push a notification in the main thread to refresh the picture in the UIImageView when the image was retrieved.